# Want to Post IGTV in Instagram in Social Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio

I want to post IGTV in Instagram from publish tab in social studio. Can i do the same? Also I am facing image size problem while creating post from social studio. Is their any way to change the image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot upload the videos longer than 60 seconds duration or 100 MB size.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ss_review_video_requirements.htm&type=5

The below article will assist you in how to upload Image,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ss_uploading_image_or_video.htm&type=5

There are limitations for both Images and Video Size, Check this for further details,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ss_create_post_ref.htm&type=5

Thanks.